# Does anybody know any keyboard shortcut for Scrivener for me to browse between folders in the binder?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm on Windows 8. I hate the use the keyboard and I just discovered scrivener and I'm loving it but I miss this option. I usually achieve that on File Explorer by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the sidebar. I'm on Win 8 Pro x64.

Comment: Hi Tom. Your question needs editing for clarity.

Comment: The binder is like the sidebar in the File (old Windows) Explorer. I wanted to navigate between the folders in it without using the mouse. This is the structure of scrivener: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/scrivener-for-dummies-cheat-sheet.html

Comment: I'm still not with you. In File Explorer on Windows 8.1, I can navigate between folders using just the keyboard, with the tab key and the arrows.

Comment: Yes but to get to there in my case I have to use Ctrl+L to select the address bar then Tab to the sidebar. In scrivener, there is no address bar.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. I have searched a lot for this feature as well, and although I have no official answer, I have seen all of the shortcuts and this one is not there.

The best thing you can do is to navigate between documents with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>UP/DOWN</kbd>. You can toggle the binder using (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) if it was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that I believe will help others with a similar question, at least for those who use Scrivener on the MacOS platform. It makes use of the history browsing keyboard shortcuts Command-[ and Command-] to navigate back and forth between files. Here is where I found this:

[Scrivener Shortvuts](http://dashkards.com/scrivener)